# How to bind the visibility of a Datagrid Column to a Checkbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have several columns in a DataGrid that I would like to be visible or hidden based on CheckBox for that column.  I searched quite a bit beforehand and found a number of different answers but in each case they either didn't work or were targeting different circumstances.

If I understand correctly ElementName won't work because the Visual Tree isn't available.  However I have tried setting the Source and RelativeSource without any luck.  In its current state it simple returns the Error:  Unresolved reference 'filterDuration'.  The error stops the program from running.

**Updated with Suggestions below and more information but still unresolved**

Here is the Converter:  (it never even steps into this)

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class FilterVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{ 
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isSelected = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);

        return isSelected ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var v = (Visibility)value; 
        return v == Visibility.Hidden ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Here is the CheckBox:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Settings">
        <DockPanel>                 
            <GroupBox Header="Filter Columns" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <ag:AutoGrid Columns="150, 150, 150" RowCount="7" RowHeight="20"> 
                    <CheckBox Content="Id" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Desc" />
                    <CheckBox x:Name="filterDuration"  Content="Duration" />                          
                </ag:AutoGrid>
            </GroupBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Here is the DataGrid:  (Extra Columns and attributes removed for brevity)

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Expander  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.shSettings}"  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Settings}" IsExpanded="True" />
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="#FF595959">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:Resources.shViolations}" Style="{StaticResource SectionHeaderText}" /> 
        </Border>
        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selecteditem}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"    >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Binding="{Binding Duration}" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference filterDuration}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource FilterVisibility}}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="CTG Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Tried in small sample and your code works fine at my end.

Comment: The CheckBox itself is in a ContentTemplate for an Expander, but the Expander starts expanded so its visible.  I wouldn't think it matters at all but I'm grasping at straws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls inside DataTemplate doesn't have same name scope and hence can't binded from controls outside it's name scope either via ElementName or x:Reference.

As a workaround you can achieve that by following way:

1. Declare a dummy checkBox under resources section.
2. Bind IsChecked of filterDuration with this dummy checkBox.
3. Bind Visibility of DataGridTextColumn with dummy checkBox IsChecked property.

---

*Code:*

```
<DockPanel .....>
   <DockPanel.Resources>
      <CheckBox x:Key="DummyCheckBox"/>
   </DockPanel.Resources>
   .........
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Binding="{Binding Duration}"
          Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource DummyCheckBox}, 
                  Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource FilterVisibility}}"/>
   ......... 
</DockPanel>
```

and in *DataTemplate*:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="filterDuration" Content="Duration"
         IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Source={StaticResource DummyCheckBox}}"/>
```

*Note* - You can also declare the resource under window resources section in case it's not accessible from Dockpanel resources section in dataTemplate.

---

Obviously ideal solution would be to:

1. Have bool property in ViewModel.
2. Bind filterDuration checkBox to that bound property.
3. Bind Visibility of dataGrid column to that bound bool property.

Comment: If you wanted a 'cleaner' way and don't mind writing some code then you could also define a new class to hold the IsChecked state (instead of abusing a dummy CheckBox for that).

Comment: @Zarat - And what exactly you meant by `abusing` here?

Comment: The fact that you create an instance of the checkbox just to use it as container for a bindable boolean property. Not exactly the point of a checkbox instance. Maybe 'abuse' was too strong a word, just saying you are using the object for something it's not intented to. Doesn't do any harm in that case, but IMHO it's not a pattern to recommend, since you usually don't know what side effects are attached to a controls property.

Comment: @Zarat - That's just a workaround I mentioned and never recommend it as an ideal solution. Also creating any DO just to hold boolean property doesn't seems correct to me. Ideal solution I have already mentioned is to bind with bool property in ViewModel. However, binding with IsChecked property doesn't incur any side-effects. If it would have then question itself is invalid where OP want to bind with IsChecked property.

Comment: I believe I learned something very key here that I wasn't aware of.  I didn't not realize that the DataTemplate had its own scope and basically couldn't see outside of it or into other DataTemplates.  This really added to the foundation of my understanding in this area.  If I could give you more than +1 I would.

Answer (score 2):

Your example works for me, you shouldn't let yourself get confused by the error in the designer, at runtime it works - x:Reference bindings seem to confuse the designer quite a bit.

Besides that, you have some minor errors in your value converter:

- ConvertBack returning 'value' is wrong, it should convert a Visbility to a Boolean.
  You should implement this correctly because you made a two-way binding. (Though I'm not sure why you are doing that, I'd say a one-way binding is enough. The visibility of a column is not something which can changed by the user after all, so no need to propagate its changes back to the checkbox, right?)
- You should declare what types your value converter handles in an attribute on the class:
  `[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]`

**UPDATE**

With your updated question you'll need a way to link the different contexts. If you can't do it by adding a property to your ViewModel you can still create a resource object. The other answer by Rohit Vats abuses a CheckBox as such a resource object. If you wanted a "cleaner" way just define a new DependencyObject subclass with a DependencyProperty for the checked state, then put an instance of that class into a static resource. This resource can then be used to have the controls communicate with each other.

Comment: The error I'm getting isn't just a designer thing, it actually throws that error when its ran.

Comment: Thanks for recommending the [ValueConversion] Tag, I hadn't used it before.  Additionally your explanation added to @Rohit Vats and gave me a few options.  Sometimes it takes hearing the same message different ways before it really clicks.